# Is there a way to keep other HTML from affecting...?

Tags: php

OK I am no beginner and I just thought I might ask is there a way in PHP to keep other Links for CSS from affecting part of the page. This is the example I am going to give you. Lets say we have some code:

```
<!-- header -->
<div>";

**(SOME PHP CODE)**

            echo open"
    include "index.php";
    echo close"

</div>
<!-- header -->
```

Well there it is, I am looking for some php code, if it exist that will insert a new page without affecting the old new. The reason why I need this is because my current header has css pages that when I include another website with new css pages, the new website destroys my current css configuration. Is there a way to insert a new php page that will remove all css code prior to loading the new one in the same page?

Comment: I read your question five times. I still can't make sense of it.

Comment: I am looking at it and thinking NO myself what do you suggest?

Comment: If you don't want to use iframes, change your CSS so that it doesn't affect the rest of the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to display content without affecting the other content on a page, I think an iframe is probably the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Either use an iframe, or if you want to include a page using php then you can do this:

```
$page = file_get_contents("index.php");
echo strip_tags($page);
```

However that would remove all the html tags from the page. Meaning, it would essentially be the text content on the page. If you just want to remove the head tags though, keeping the links and images and such, but without the `<style>` and `<link>` tags (i.e. without styling), do this

```
$page = file_get_contents("index.php");
echo preg_replace("#<head(.*?)>(.*?)</head>#is","",$page);
```

Then you can use the css on your page and style (if you know the ids and classes on the other page)